# Oracle arrays "contains" function

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle

I want to store a list of primary keys to other records in the same table. I then want to be able to perform a select that resembles something like:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myarraycol CONTAINS '123'`

I've seen that Oracle has an [array data type](http://psoug.org/definition/ARRAY.htm). However it looks like the EXISTS function only verifies if the element exists at the specified index. Is there a way to verify that a given variable is in the array data type column in a single SQL query?

As an alternative to using the array data type I tried storing the PKs as a comma-delimited string like "123,324,543,23432." My query then looked like:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mystringcol LIKE '%123%'`

if I wanted all records with the PK '123' in it. The problem with this (among many others) is that if another record has a value "432,9912399,432" this record will show up because of the "123" in the "9912399."

One way I could solve this problem using "LIKE" and string could be to have my where clause be:

`WHERE mystringcol LIKE '%,123,% OR mystringcol LIKE '%123, OR mystringcol LIKE '%,123`

to test for "123" being in the middle, start or end of the entire string, but that starts to get ugly and I'd rather not do it this way.

Has anyone done something like this before and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: This way of implementing many-to-many relationships will bring you a lot of headaches down the road. Why don't you use a proper junction table?

Comment: I have over 10,000 records (and that's just part of the data). My original logic for avoiding using more tables was that the data would all be in one place and that the SQL would run faster. However I realize now that removing one of these PKs from a specified row would be annoying.

Comment: 10k records is nothing. We deal with tables with millions of rows every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory Oracle has MEMBER OF function for collection but regarding 3rd normal form you idea looks strange.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE member_of_example AS
  2    TYPE nestedTableType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
  3    myTable1 nestedTableType;
  4    result BOOLEAN;
  5  BEGIN
  6    myTable1 := nestedTableType('F', 'G', 'S');
  7    result := 'George' MEMBER OF myTable1;
  8    IF result THEN
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('''George'' is a member');
 10    END IF;
 11  END member_of_example;
 12  /
```

An example for function to get the plsql table from comma-separated stuff:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function Str2NmbTbl(p_str varchar2) return number_table is
l_col number_table := number_table();
l_pos number;
l_cnt number := 1;
l_num number;
begin     
    l_pos := instr(p_str, '[', l_cnt);
    while l_pos > 0 loop       
        l_num := to_number(substr(p_str, l_pos + 1, instr(p_str, ']', 1, l_cnt) - l_pos - 1));
        l_col.extend;

        l_col(l_cnt) := l_num;
        l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
        l_pos := instr(p_str, '[', l_pos + 1);
    end loop;  

    return l_col;
end;
/

with s as
(select 1 id, '[11412][21][3131][3333]'    str from dual union all
 select 2 id, '[64376][553]'               str from dual union all
 select 3 id, '[5943][74621][19][3333][0]' str from dual union all
 select 4 id, '[21593][22321][43][094]'    str from dual --union all
)
select id, Str2NmbTbl(str) collctn
from s;
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your example. It appears to operate on a table with a varchar2(10) column that determines if "George" is in any of the rows?

Comment: But you could parse your structure into collection and apply my example

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b32258/api.htm#CHDFEEJD - if you have apex installed